# A word that can mean the "outsider"

Tags: meaning

I'm looking for words that can meaning the "outsider" social group but not in context of "loser". Not an "opposition" group but just different; a group that stay aside of mainstream and popular themes. Any guesses?

Comment: Do you mean in high school, or in college/university, or later in life?  Most of us here are no longer in high school, so we may not be familiar with latest slang used therein.

Comment: Also it's unclear what you mean by "mainstream and popular themes". Please give some example of "themes" that non-outsiders (the main stream) follow.

Comment: In the 1960s and 1970s, a generic name for "outsider group" was "the out crowd"—a play on "the in crowd," which was used to designate the most admired or socially dominant group in the relevant social setting. Both terms may be rather dated now, however.

Comment: No one mentioned "alien"?

Answer (score 3):

Outsider is a good word, and fairly neutral. Outlier is more neutral:

> One that lives or is located outside or at the edge of a given area; one that exists outside or at an extreme of a category, pattern, or expectation - AHDEL/TFD

Words with a somewhat positive connotations:

[Nonconformist](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nonconformist):

> a person who does not conform to generally accepted patterns of behaviour or thought; of or characterized by behaviour that does not conform to generally accepted patterns (Random House Dictionary/TFD)

Also maverick; original, eccentric, bohemian; dissident, dissenter, iconoclast, heretic; outsider.

[Recusant](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/recusant) is a fancier word:

> dissenter; a nonconformist; a person who refuses to submit, comply, etc. - TFD

It really depends on the context and the meaning you want.

Comment: Neat, now I can use *recusant recluse*.

Comment: Yes, outsider is good but it have negative context / memory initiations, like "loosers" or "castaways"

Comment: @user116739 - It kinda depends on who you ask. Personally, an outsider does not carry that connotation to me. Also depends on if being an *insider* is considered important to you. But, again, "outlier" is even more neutral. It almost has a statistical feel to it. Einstein was an outlier. Malcolm Gladwell wrote a book called *Outliers: The Story of Success*.

Answer (score 0):

A buzz-word that is currently used for these purposes - and is full of myriad connotations - is: ***"alternative".***

Answer (score 0):

Consider **independent**

> 1) not influenced or controlled by others in matters of opinion, conduct, etc.; thinking or acting for oneself
>   2) not subject to another's authority or jurisdiction; autonomous; free
>   3) not influenced by the thought or action of others
>   6) rejecting others' aid or support; refusing to be under obligation to others.

(from Dictionary.com)

An independent group may or may not be philosophically aligned with mainstream groups, but they often maintain their distance in one or more ways consistent with the definition. But the word implies that any alignment with the mainstream is by deliberate choice rather than by group pressure.

Here is a little more on some words already mentioned:

**Nonconformist** or **nonconforming** come to mind if the word has to emphasize the non-mainstream character of the group.

The adjective **maverick** can mean *unorthodox, unconventional, nonconformist*. But calling someone a maverick is to emphasize not just heir independence from the mainstream, but also their tendency to depart from mainstream thought in an uncontrollable way (untamable).

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be *rebel*

[TFD definition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rebel)

> 1. To refuse allegiance to and oppose by force an established government or ruling authority.
> 2. To resist or defy an authority or a generally accepted convention.
> 3. To feel or express strong unwillingness or repugnance

Other options which I don't like so much are *renegade* and *hipster*

Answer (score -1):

Slang: ***blow-in*, *floater*, *bum face***

***drifter, vagrant, vagabond, itinerant, gypsy, wanderer, hobo, tramp, migrant, nomad, ne'er-do- well***

> [**A Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English**](https://books.google.com/books?id=IAjyQdFwh4UC&pg=PA99&dq=%22blow-in%22%20slang&hl=en&sa=X&ei=IHcrVfqZMsGdygSS9IBw&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22blow-in%22%20slang&f=false)- Page 99 Eric
>   Partridge - 2006 
>   _
>
> 1800, then S.E. **blow-in, n. A newcomer, esp. one still unaccepted**:
>
> _
>
> [**The Doubleday Roget's Thesaurus in Dictionary Form**](https://books.google.com/books?id=0kl60ksCG5QC&pg=PA261#v=onepage&q&f=false)- Page 261 Sidney
>   L. Landau - 2009
>
> **floater n. drifter, vagrant, vagabond, itinerant, gypsy, wanderer,
>   hobo, tramp, migrant, nomad, ne'er-do- well**
>
> _ 
>   [**A Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English**](https://books.google.com/books?id=IAjyQdFwh4UC&pg=PA153&dq=%22bum%20face%22%20slang&hl=en&sa=X&ei=k3srVc-DKYqmyASupYGQCw&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22bum%20face%22%20slang&f=false) - Page 153 Eric
>   Partridge - 2006
>
> **bum-face. A low derogatory form of address**.

Comment: Links to definitions, your reasonings or explanations?

Comment: @Mazura Here you have them